# I have problems with low beam and cruise control on my Holden Commodore VY

Tags: electrical, battery, wiring, holden

Headlights were working fine. Low beam is now too dim to see with ( Both sides) High beam still works well. Cruise Control was working well, but now works on and off, sometimes for a while, next time I try it doesn't work, then it does. Could the low beam and cruise control problems related?

Is it wiring, as the fuses are all good, and I brought a new low beam relay, which did not fix the problem for the headlights. It's not the bulbs and seems strange it is both sides at once.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the voltage at the battery (should be ~13.1vdc), then also check the output of the alternator during operation (should be ~14.2vdc).